# Can I get the field MobilePhone2 from Outlook Contacts REST API?

Tags: api, outlook

I'm using Outlook Contacts REST API in order to get all phone numbers saved for a given contact.

I have to call both versions of the API (`v2.0` & `beta`) so I can get almost all values.
ie. `v2.0` send me this:

```
HomePhones: [ '0333333333', '0444444444' ],
MobilePhone1: '0611111111',
BusinessPhones: [ '0155555555', '0166666666' ],
```

and `beta` send me this:

```
Phones: [
    { Type: 'Home', Number: '0333333333' },
    { Type: 'Business', Number: '0155555555' },
    { Type: 'Mobile', Number: '0611111111' },
    { Type: 'Other', Number: '0677777777' }
],
```

However, my contact looks like this:

[image: Outlook contact screenshot]

As you can see, both API send me different results, and none of them is complete.
Moreover, the contact I saved in my account has one more phone number, `Mobile2`, and none of the APIs send it to me.

Is there a way to get it?

Thank you,

bjorge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API doesn't expose this directly. However, you can always request it as an [extended property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/extended-properties-rest-operations#get-item-expanded-with-extended-property) using the correct MAPI property tag details.

I examined a contact with [MFCMapi](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) and I see that the Mobile2 number is stored in `PR_CAR_TELEPHONE_NUMBER`, which is a string property with the property ID of 0x3A1E. So, since you're using the Outlook REST endpoint, your request would look something like this:

```
GET /me/contacts?$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties(
  $filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A1E')
```

If you were using Graph, the request would look a little different:

```
GET /me/contacts?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties(
  $filter=id eq 'String 0x3A1E')
```

Finally, I'd recommend voting up this UserVoice request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/19861435-beef-up-contact-resource-contents-in-rest-api